# How to use sed to keep the first two words in the last occurrence of []

Tags: unix, replace, sed

I have a file like

```
one two three [four five] six seven [eight nine ten yeah]   
new york [los angeles houston]    
usa canada [mexico costa rica] brasil [yes no]
```

I want to keep the first two words in the last pair []:

```
eight nine
los angeles
yes no
```

I have tried several command but it doesn't work. Can anyone give me some suggestions? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This `awk` should work with a custom field separator:

```
awk -F'[][]' '{split($(NF-1), a, " "); print a[1], a[2]}' file
eight nine
los angeles
yes no
```

- Regex `[][]` makes `[` OR `]` a field separator
- `NF-1` will give you last text between `[` and `]`
- `split` function is used to split the text by space.

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking the tick mark on top-left side of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
$ sed -r 's/.*\[([^ ]+) ([^] ]+).*/\1 \2/' input
eight nine
los angeles
yes no
```

**OR**

```
$ sed -r 's/.*\[([^] ]+) ?([^] ]*).*/\1 \2/' input
```

Comment: @potong Yeah i thought of that too. But op didnt mention clearly on that. Anyways i have added that too :)

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -ne 's/^.*\[\([^ ]* [^ ]*\)[^]]*\][^][]*$/\1/p'
```

That is: replace the entire line up through a set of square brackets that don't have any square brakcets after them with the first two groups of nonspaces inside the brackets and the space between them.

`^` start of line

`.*` any number of characters, including 0; exact match will be determined by what can match the rest of the expression.

`\[` a literal open bracket

`\(`...`\)` means "remember the part of the line that matched this part of the expression".

`[^ ]* [^ ]*` means "any number of non-space characters, followed by a space, followed by any number of non-space characters".  In other words: exactly two words.

`[^]]*` matches any number of non-close-bracket characters - so, everything up to the close bracket.

`\]` matches the close bracket itself.

`[^][]*$` matches anything but brackets to the end of the line.  This keeps the expression from matching a set of brackets earlier in the line.

So we search for that, and then replace it with `\1`, which is the part of the line matched by the part of the expression between the first pair of `\(`...`\)` - the first two words in the bracket.